# PHP creating an array from form input fields

Tags: php, html, forms, input, name-attribute

I'm trying to create an array to store numbers and add them together.

```
<input type="number" name="numbers[]"/>
```

I'm getting an undefined variable on the following line

```
foreach($numbers as $number)
```

I'm sure this is probably something basic but I'm relatively new to php and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the sum of an array you dont need to loop you can use `array_sum`

Example

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['numbers'])) {
    echo array_sum($_POST['numbers']);
}

?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="number" name="numbers[]"/>
<input type="number" name="numbers[]"/>
<input type="number" name="numbers[]"/>
<input type="number" name="numbers[]"/>
<input type="submit" value="add"/>
</form>
```

Comment: can u tell me what is the actual name that will be passed to check if field is actually filled in or empty.

Comment: It would come like this `$_POST['numbers'][0]` `$_POST['numbers'][1]` etc. If you still have troubles let me know so that i can update the answer with examples

Comment: thanks i should be able to finish it from there

Answer (score 2):

If you posted the `input`s you're showing from one page to another and you need to run through the list you should set it up like this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['numbers']) && is_array($_REQUEST['numbers'])) {
  $numbers = $_REQUEST['numbers'];

  foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    print $number;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mayb add an isset($_REQUEST['numbers']) to that...

Answer (score 0):

Add some more code, but it basically means that $numbers is not declared yet at this point in the code.

Add this line before:

```
$numbers = array();
```

Now it shouldnt give you this error.

So now the question is, where is $numbers supposed to be set? For that we need more info and code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert but if I understand you correctly and you are trying to put a variable in an array you would need to say what part of the Array I would assume. I'm pretty sure that `$array[i]` and `$array` are not the same and that if you try to put something into `$array` it will only be able to hold one thing at a time. If you are just gathering a bunch of numbers that someone enters from a form then you could do something like this.

```
//For the form
<form action="formHandler.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="number1">
  <input type="text" name="number2">
  //continue in this manner for as many numbers as you need to gather.
</form>

//for the PHP side of it.
<?php
  $x=1;
  $numbersArray = array();
  for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
   $numbersArray[$i] = $_POST['number'.$x];
   $x++;
  }
//to add them up
$total=array_sum($numbersArray);
?>
```

I hope that's right and I hope it helps.

Comment: PHP has more concise ways to do this.  See other answers for examples.

Also, if you actually have 10 numbers in your array, then you either need to start looping from 0 (preferred, imo, because you don't have to subtract 1 for the array index) or change your while test to $i <= 10 (and that should be $i, not just i); for that matter, a for loop is really better here than a while loop.

Comment: I was trying to mark it up quickly so it wasn't up to snuff. I agree on that bit about for loops and about i but like I said, I'm not an expert and I forgot the correct for loop syntax so I was just running with the while loops. I didnt know about the array_sum thing, that's pretty cool.

Comment: You should be able to edit your answer.

Comment: @GreenMatt I edited it to make it nicer and I'm now enrolled in a PHP course :D Thanks for the code suggestions.