# Entering numbers from form input into an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, input

```
<form  method="post" action = "handler.php" > 
<input type="text" name="number1"  /> 
<input type="text" name="number2"  />
<input type="text" name="number3"  />
<input type="text" name="number4"  />
<input type="text" name="number5"  />
 etc..
```

I have a form set up like this to take in 10 different numbers. I want to add each of these numbers to an array so that I can sort the numbers. I know *sort* is a built in function but I want to write my own sorting algorithms I just need to get all of numbers into an array so I can pass it my functions.

```
$numArr = array ();
```

I have tried everything from array_push to call the $_POST['number1'] directly in the array itself. Every time I do *echo $numArr* all i get is an empty array as an output.

Comment: Make it easier by just using the form input name array syntax `<input name="numbers[]">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP creating an array from form input fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533044/php-creating-an-array-from-form-input-fields)

Comment: Ok I didn't realize that was a viable way of doing it. Very new to PHP. And i had reviewed the other link you listed beforehand but I couldn't really follow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use same name of input element and make it an array like,

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php"> 
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" /> 
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" />
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" />
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" />
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" />
</form>
```

Now, When you submit your form on `handler.php` you will get an array of `numbers[]`.

```
$_POST['numbers'];
```

You can sort array using `sort()`.

```
$sort_array = sort($_POST['numbers']);
```

If you print `$sort_array` then you can see sorted array elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php"> 
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" /> 
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" />
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" />
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" />
  <input type="text" name="numbers[]" />
</form>
```

when submitted...

```
sort($_POST['numbers']);
```

Comment: I know _sort_ is a built in function but I wanted to dabble into writing my own sorting algorithms I just needed a way to add all of the values into an array as their integer value. I tried $numArr =  ($_POST['numbers']); but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: `$numArr = $_POST['numbers'];` ...no parenthesis ... or use it directly.

Comment: You don't have to declare $numArr as an array first? I just realized I forgot to put that in to my previous comment. It should be $numArr = array($_POST['numbers']); Which didn't work for me unless I am doing something else wrong.

Comment: You should read a beginners guide to PHP and stop asking useless questions.